# i am getting "Error generating image." Files permission is 777 and gd library is installed

Tags: 7, media

I had installed gd library and also given 755 permission to the files but i am getting 500 - error generating issue in my drupal

My site URL is http://vestcom.ca/dev/

One of example URL of error is http://vestcom.ca/dev/?q=sites/default/files/styles/cardealer-car-mini-thumbnail/public/property-photos/IMG_1373.JPG&itok=_DfNUQVW

If anybody have any idea about how do i debug this or how can i get image then please let me know.

Comment: You'll need to inspect your web server error logs to find the actual exception, nothing we can do to help without that

Comment: Your permission is not set if you'll access http://vestcom.ca/dev/?q=sites/default/files/styles/cardealer-car-mini-thumbnail as anonymous, try to set their also the same permission which you have provided for the parent folder. Make Sense! Try it and let me know.

Comment: their is nothing in error log. At very first time i thought that it was due to file permission i checked it and found nothing.

Comment: A 500 without a real exception is, let's say, rare. I would check again (you server error logs, not Drupal error logs). But regardless, without any information to go on how could anyone here answer this?

Comment: @RishiKulshreshtha the file and folder permission is 777

Comment: @Clive i am talking about server error log. Anyone who got this type of error before can easily answer the question :)

Comment: Well sure, but the answer is: check your server error logs to find out what the problem is. If there are no errors, you need to step-debug your site. I'm not sure what sort of answer you're expecting to get from us here without providing any information. Remember, this is a Q+A site, not a personal support forum. If you don't provide enough information for this to be useful to future visitors, it'll wind up being closed.

Comment: @Clive All I need to ask that is their any way except debugging the whole code. Because this is a cms many people had uses it and i am quite sure that many of them got this error so i am trying to get help to debug and resolve it really quick

Comment: @keshu_vats: Try to understand what Clive is saying to you. If possible please provide us some more detail or else your question is incomplete to us and we can't further help you on this.

Comment: @RishiKulshreshtha  I am new to drupal so i don’t know about its core functionality the error is coming from 'modules/image/image.module' file this code is returning false "  $success = file_exists($derivative_uri) || image_style_create_derivative($style, $image_uri, $derivative_uri);" the file exists but the image_uri path is something like public://path_to_image i donot know what the "public://" stands for in file path

Comment: _All I need to ask that is their any way except debugging the whole code._ Ah ok, the answer to that is simply "no". If you really don't have any server error messages (which I honestly find very hard to believe; not suggesting you're lying but maybe you don't know where they are?), then you need to step through the site  in operation, and inspect variables at the point of failure. That will tell you what's wrong, nobody here can because we don't have access to your site (and even if we did there are far too many possible answers for this to be useful to future visitors).

Comment: Sorry, but until we see some information that might help us to help you, this needs to be closed. Once you've got some more information to go on, just edit the question and flag it for re-opening, or give me a shout in the comments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your image toolkit (URI /admin/config/media/image-toolkit). You must see like this
[image]

Comment: Could you explain how this answers the question? Are you saying one should use ImageMagick instead of GD to stop this error?

Comment: Using ImageMagick instead of GD solves the issue.